# Is there is a way to make a button in google sheet related to a google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there is a way to create a button in a google sheet that is bonded to a google app script written in its related script editor? Instead of selecting tools then script editor and then pressing run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste an image of a button above (not in a cell). Right click and you can reposition. You will also see the snowman / sub sandwich / 3 vertical dots. Click that and ASSIGN SCRIPT